# models.ForeignKey field not showing up in the browsable API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I have **two models** `Requests` and `Events` that have foreign keys back to the `User` model. When trying to post with foreign key data using Django Rest Framework, I am receiving a **null constraint error**. It seems django is not accepting the **user_id** (`requester_id` and `event_admin_id`) references. In the browsable API the foreign key sections (`requester_id` and `event_id`) are not present. Is it being hidden by something? Note that event_participant is made up of only Foreign Keys but they appear in the browsable API when posting. I'm not sure what could be the difference

[Missing event_admin_id foreignkey field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krtg3.png)
[Missing request_admin_id fk field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G3EV.png)

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_job_description = models.CharField(max_length =  200)
    user_profile_pic = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True)


class Event(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
         return self.event_name
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    event_location = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    event_description = models.TextField(max_length = 300)
    admin_user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'event_admin')

class Request(models.Model):
     def __str__(self):
        return self.request_desc
     requester_user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'requests')
     request_desc = models.TextField(max_length = 100)
     fulfiller_user_id = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
     fulfilled_status = models.BooleanField()


class Event_Participant(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.event_id)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'event_attendee')
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name = 'event')
```

**serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from crewboardsdb.models import Event
from crewboardsdb.models import Request
from crewboardsdb.models import Event_Participant
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    requests = serializers.StringRelatedField(many = True)
    event_admin = serializers.StringRelatedField(many = True)
    event_attendee= serializers.StringRelatedField(many = True)
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id','username','first_name','last_name','email','user_job_description','event_admin','requests', 'event_attendee',)

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    admin_user_id = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'event_name', 'admin_user_id', 'event_description', 'event_location',)
        lookup_field = 'admin_user_id'




class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    requester_user_id = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ('id', 'request_desc', 'fulfilled_status','requester_user_id','fulfiller_user_id',)
        lookup_field = 'requester_user_id'




class EventParticipantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event_Participant
        fields = ('id', 'event_id', 'user_id')
```

Comment: I should add that these fields were visible yesterday, i'm not sure what could have changed.

Answer (score 2):

Hope that this is still active, had the same problem just now and figured it out.

In my case I had the exact same issue as well, foreign key related attributes were not shown inside the browsable api, so I thought it had to be something with the serializers.

Turns out that is exactly the problem. If you have a `ForeignKey` constraint, you don't have to deal with nestes serializers at all, just leave them out of your serializer class!

In your case, it would be like this:

```
(Event Model)
class Event(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
         return self.event_name
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    event_location = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    event_description = models.TextField(max_length = 300)
    admin_user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name =    'event_admin')
```

Here your `admin_user_id` is probably the attribute which isn't showing up in your browsable api.

Now, this is how your serializer for that class has to look like:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'event_name', 'admin_user_id', 'event_description', 'event_location',)
        lookup_field = 'admin_user_id'
```

Note that just cutting out the line `admin_user_id = serializers.StringRelatedField()` did the job, now your api should show the field as expected and you are able to select a user to link this object to.

I tested your problem inside my own project by simply taking your model and serializer, following this simple step did the job!

Hope this still helps you or anyone in the future. Cheers.

Comment: if you remove the StringRelatedField you do get the dropdown in the browsable api, but you give up the string representation in the response (which is probably the whole point of using that option in the first place)